# If $Y = \{0,1\}$, are $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ necessarily open? What am I missing in this proof?

Tags: general-topology

I don't believe they're necessarily open. I think a counterexample is the topology $\{Y, \emptyset\}$. However a book I'm reading has the following theorem and proof:

> Let $Y = \{0,1\}$ and $X$ be a topological space. $X$ is connected if and only if the only continuous mappings $f : X \to Y$ are the constant mappings.
>
> Proof:
>
> Let $f: X \to Y$ be a continuous non constant mapping. Then $P = f^{-1}(\{0\})$ and $Q = f^{-1}(\{1\})$ are non empty and $P \ne Y$ and $P \ne \emptyset$. $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are open sets and $f$ is continuous therefore...

and goes on to show that $P$ and $Q$ are disjoint open sets. So is the inference that $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are open sets warranted and I'm missing something here? Or am I just meant to assume that $Y$ is a topological space with  $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ open.

Comment: There is an unstated assumption that $Y$ is equipped with the discrete topology (i.e. the subspace topology inherited from $\Bbb{R}$). The result is indeed false for general topologies on $Y$.

Comment: Please, if you reference a book, say the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this property with $S^0$ and with $2$ instead of $Y$. Both this spaces are (the same): a two point space with discrete topology. In your text, the assumption is that $Y$ is precisely $2$ (that is' it has discrete topology). A counter example of non-discrete space $\{0,1\}$ is the [Sierpiński space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space).

Note: $S^n=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\mid \|x\|_2=1\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $2=\{0,1\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ (both subspaces of Euclidean topology).

Comment: I'm unsure of the notation: $||x||_2$, what does that mean?

Comment: In the context of $(\mathbb{R}^n,+)$ as a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, for every $p\in [1,\infty)$, $\|(x_1,\dots, x_n)\|_p=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p\right)^{1/p}$ and is called the $p$-norm (for $p=\infty$ you just take the limit of the previous expression (over $p$) which happens to be $\max\{x_1,\dots, x_n\}$). For $p=2$, it's just Pythagoras. That is, $S^n$ is the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. In particular, $S^0=\{-1,1\}$.

Comment: Got it thanks. So you mean to say that considered as a subspace of the Elucidean topology on the reals, one can deduce the openness of the sets of their two elements? Also wouldn't this be true for any subspace of of the reals with Elucidean topology with exactly two points? $Y$ =$\{a,b\}$, $\{a\} = Y \cap B(a; \frac{|a-b|}{2})$, $\{b\} = Y \cap B(b; \frac{|a-b|}{2})$

Comment: Exactly, here $\{0,1\}$ is considered as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ giving it discrete topology, your reasoning is correct. Fun fact, the topology of $\mathbb{N}$ (discrete topology) is precisely the subspace topology it gets from $\mathbb{R}$. You can also consider $\{0,1\}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{N}$, giving it, again, the discrete topology.

Comment: I see, yeah that makes sense. Thanks for the help